# EF 4.3.1 How to map a sub sub class with table per type

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.3

I have an abstract base class called Party. There are several concrete subclasses (Company, Person, Department).  Party has a property called PartyType which is use as the discriminator. Each type is in its own table with configurations like

```
Map<Person>(p => p.Requires("PartyType").HasValue("Person").ToTable("People");
```

Everything works well.
Now I want to add a subclass of Person called Employee. How do I map this? I've tried

```
Map<Employee>(e => e.Requires("PartyType").HasValue("Employee")
   .ToTable("Employees");
```

but this gives a runtime error of

> (43,10) : error 3032: Problem in mapping fragments starting at lines
>   43, 84:EntityTypes WOL.EFData.Person, WOL.EFData.Employee are being
>   mapped to the same rows in table People. Mapping conditions can be
>   used to distinguish the rows that these types are mapped to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In table per type mapping EF does not expect a discriminator configuration.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().ToTable("People");
modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>().ToTable("Employees");
```

See [this article](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/28/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt.aspx) for more information.